# how to run multiple website with single database in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to run multiple site:-

```
i.e http://example.com
&   http://backend.example.com
```

both websites will be connected to single database.
how can i do that because wordpress reads siturl from the database.

Comment: Checkout wordpress multisite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found answer to my question, i am posting here so that it may help others:-

in both website upload the same wp_config.php (which have same database details)

copy your wp_options table to other table name lets name it : wp_options_site_2
and update its siteurl(you second site domain).
keep first site as it is. go to second site > wp_includes open wp_db.php find set_prefix function add this line **before the return statement**:-

```
$this->options = 'wp_options_site_2';
```

Comment: It works on home page but did not work on internal pages.

Comment: @RizwanShamsherKaimKhani there must be some hard coded data. if you you use site_url(). it will work. i am doing this trick on multiple websites and both are working fine.

Answer (score 1):

There can be two ways of having two wordpress websites using the same database:
1. Set different table prefixes for both the websites, keeping the database same.
2. Use the WordPress multisite feature.
Check out https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_Multiple_Blogs

Comment: both solution will not work for me. because basically both site will be same ( one is the light version of the orginal site.)

Comment: A light version of the same site? How about just switching theme based on whatever condition you set? that sounds more logical to me. What do you need a lighter version for, anyway?

Comment: my website is very heavy! i want a lighter version which will have less features so that in can load in less time.